# iOS - Use responseObject outside of AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking

I want to display the responseObject received from the below AFNetworking call in my tableview cell. I created an NSMutableArray property in my header file (neighbourData) thinking allocating responseObject to it might work. Though as predicted, I can't seem to use the data outside of the AFNetworking method. On the other hand, placing the AFNetworking method inside of my tableview cell works, but there is a lag time in waiting for the data to display in my UIlabels. Any ideas?

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *neighbourData;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        NSMutableDictionary *viewParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [viewParams setValue:@"u000" forKey:@"view_name"];
        [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            self.neighbourData = [responseObject mutableCopy];
            NSLog(@"This is the neighbourdata %@",self.neighbourData);


        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }];

       }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *NetworkTableIdentifier = @"sidebarCell";

    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    sidebarCell *cell = (sidebarCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NetworkTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)

    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"sidebarCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

      NSDictionary *userName = [self.neighbourData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       [[cell username] setText:[userName objectForKey:@"users_name"]];

        NSDictionary *userBio = [self.neighbourData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell userDescription] setText:[userBio objectForKey:@"userbio"]];


    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Why haven;t you reloaded table as soon as you got your response..

Comment: `self.neighbourData = [responseObject mutableCopy];` soon after this line you should reload your table. Also  make sure that your datasource for table is this neighbour data. Also try to caste the nsarray in different way like `self.neighbourData = (NSMutableArray *)responseObject;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialise neighbourData with the responce object or just pass its refrence to your arry and then reload the table. it will work

```
self.neighbourData = [NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArry: responseObject]];
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

OR

```
self.neighbourData = (NSMutableArray *)responseObject;
[yourTableView reloadData];
```